# WooCommerce Import Orders Tax Calculation

Tags: woocommerce, tax

When I import orders, the VAT is calculated for the orders. The store is located in the Netherlands with a 21% tax rate (for the products in the store). The tax settings are configured to calculate tax based on the customer's address. When an order is imported, the VAT is calculated. However, this does not happen as expected. If the order has a total of €179.00, I expect to see this in the total field.

What currently happens is that the Dutch tax is deducted to calculate the product price. Then, the tax from the customer's country is added. So, if the order is €179.00 and needs to be shipped to, for example, Germany where the tax rate is 19%, the calculation looks like this:

€179.00 – €31.07 = €149.93 * 1.19 (€28.48) = €178.41 because the Dutch tax rate is subtracted first, and then the VAT is calculated based on this product price, changing the total amount of the order.

What I expect to happen is this:

€179.00 / 1.19 = €150.42 (product price) €150.42 + €28.58 = €179.00
So, I expect to see the price of the product as €150.42, the tax amount (for Germany) as €28.58, and the total amount unchanged at €179.00.

How can i fix this

Comment: Are you using a plugin to import these orders? how do you import these orders?

Comment: Yes I'm using the plugin from Effect Connect,

https://github.com/EffectConnect/MarketplacesPluginWooCommerce

The strange part is that i have contacted them and they don't have this problem when they test it. but no matter what i do i keep getting this problem. 

also have setup a testing site with only this plugin and woocommerce and a storefront theme and still the same problem. even when the settings are all exactly the same.